# Spring Data and SQL Server getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as' error

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to use Spring Data to read from a SQL Server table.  I have native queries that work fine, but I want to use a Spring Repository and find() methods instead.

I have an Entity defined:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my table")
// This native query works when I try and use it.
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Associate.getDistinctBusinessUnits",
    query = "SELECT DISTINCT bus_unit_name FROM \"my table\" ORDER BY bus_unit_name"
)
public class Associate {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "assoc_oper_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
    public String assocOperId;

...
}
```

and a Respoitory

```
@Repository
public interface AssociateRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Associate, String> {
    List<String> getDistinctBusinessUnits();
}
```

and my controller is calling the repository

```
// This query fails.
final Optional<Associate> result = associateRepository.findById(associateId);
```

but when it does I get

```
12147 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
12181 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/roster-service] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:256)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:592)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:522)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2930)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:444)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:569)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:388)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:356)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.findAll(Unknown Source)
        at com.cerner.abilities.roster.service.controllers.AssociatesController.getAssociates(AssociatesController.java:59)
        at com.cerner.abilities.roster.service.controllers.AssociatesController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a1313748.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.my.project.controllers.AssociatesController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$34fe814.getAssociates(<generated>)
```

I know that my DB connection is working fine as my native query Repository method works as expected.  I've tried several different flavors of existing Repository methods plus ones I defined to try and get the same error.

My spring configuration is

```
# ===============================
# DATABASE
# ===============================

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://grddwmrtwhqipdw.northamerica.cerner.net:1433;databaseName=IPDW_PROD02
spring.datasource.username=ablab
spring.datasource.password=ablab


# ===============================
# JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.3 with Spring Data 2.1.5 (I did try Spring Data 2.1.3 in case they needed to be in step) which I believe are the current latest versions available.

I don't own the DB server and don't know how to definitively check the version from SQL but I have tried several different dialects.  I also don't know where there's a definitive list of all available dialects for a driver so I don't know if I tried them all.

I'm not terribly experienced with Spring nor Spring Data.  I've used the Repository in similar sorts of ways against Oracle without problem so my guess is a peculiarity with SqlServer.

Anyone have some ideas where to go from here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is there another query somewhere? This query doesn't have the `AS` keyword anywhere

Comment: And why are you trying to inject double-quotes anyway? Use square brackets (e.g. `[my table]`) around poorly chosen names so you don't have to fight with string delimiters.

Comment: or just use single quote.

Comment: I added some comments to try and clear things up.  The annotated native query works fine...though could be refined as noted.  It's the "associateRepository.findById(associateId)" call that's failing.  The query generated from that call is outside my control.  In fact, every JPA automagically generated query from my Repository fails with similar complaints about syntax even though I don't control the syntax...JPA/Hibernate does.

Comment: The root cause appears to be that some of the columns on my table have spaces in the column names and JPA is not wrapping them appropriately.  Similar to what Siddharth mentions but within the query built by the Repository and NOT in my native query.  What I don't know is what options to set to alter JPA's behavior to escape the spaces properly when it builds the query for me.

Answer (score 3):

@Table(name = "my table") should be @Table(name = "`my table`")

Comment: I commented on the original question, but that query is the example of a working query.  It's the automagical Spring Repository generated queries that I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: This isn't the right answer, but it's similar to the root problem.  The problem I'm hitting is that JPA is building a query that doesn't handle spaces in column names properly.  I don't know how to tell JPA/Hibernate to protect the spaces in column/table names.  Any experience there?